# OOP, add class variables directly to a class, without define them before

Tags: php, oop

My question is very simple, I saw this code in a class:

```
class controller_activity {
    function __construct($args) {
        //the variable template is not defined or what happen??
        $this->template = new Template('activity');     
    }
    .......
```

Usually I see the declaration of variables in a class like "public $template" or similar, but this case, is the same that if I define those variables as usual?, can I add variables in this way directly?, without defining them before?, is it recomendable?

Comment: Is the code from a running system? Are you sure the template is not defined somewhere below this lines of code and you just missed it when checking?

Comment: nono, they are the first lines of many codes, and they are working without problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the same that if I define those variables as usual?,

No, the definition is missing. [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/get_object_vars) will show them, but [`get_class_vars`](http://php.net/get_class_vars) won't.

> can I add variables in this way directly?,

Yes, that is possible. They will be publicly visible.

> without defining them before?,

Yes, without defining them before. They will be publicly visible.

> is it recomendable?

That depends. Normally not, but there are exceptions to this rule.

Comment: I can';t think of many cases where it's recommendable. For anything you plan on adding to a class after it's instantiated, it would seem that an associative array `$properties` or the like should be used, with clear documentation as to what it does.

Comment: @ColinMorelli: A well known exception are PHP's weak `stdClass` which just works that way. Normally when you implement a concrete type, you don't want that, true. If you have some meta-data handling in your system(s), you can also create those with assigning public properties to object instances on the fly. Sure this tends to be more fragile, however as long as this is within processings, it's still quite stable. However, you are right, I still won't recommend this.

Comment: Fair, `stdClass` does work that way - but I think we both know that there are a lot of things that the PHP core does that are completely wrong. I assumed that your "there are exceptions to this rule" comment was referring to their being cases where it is recommendable, not where it is done in practice ;)

Comment: Well exceptions to recommendation rules are - at least in my eyes - *never* recommendations. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why this code works is because the `$this->template` assignment is happening in the `__construct()` which happens pretty much immediately on class instantiation. So this could be seen as a sloppy—but fudgable—way of doing variable assignment. But it doesn’t help for readability or debugging later on.  So the answer is yes, you can do this. Is it a "best practice?" 100% no.

Answer (score 1):

While not recommended, PHP and it's non-constraining (weakly typed) use of variables means that it is possible to declare class vars on the fly.

I've done it by accident on a number of occasions, but then gone back and defined them properly. By default they will have the `public` access method (the same behavior as not including an access method at the head of the class, i.e. `$var = 0` versus `private $var = 0`).

Again, this is not recommended. I haven't tested for it specifically, but I would imagine that they throw a `Notice` error. The other issue is that doing this makes code harder to follow, either for yourself later on or another developer trying to work with your class.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted will work without a problem.

In PHP you can use undeclared variables. In other languages (like Java), you can't use undeclared variables. It's simply a matter of style, but I personally don't like using them.

Note that the template var, if undeclared as in your example, has public [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)